# Copy Ctor with Linked Lists

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, deep-copy

I am having a ton of trouble achieving a deep copy when using linked lists.  I am pretty sure the problem is that using otherList.listData->  is giving me a pointer to the data in the original list rather than copying over the values.  However, I am baffled as to how I can directly access that data otherwise.  I was thinking you could just derefence those pointers but I must have the wrong syntax on that.  There are also no get/set methods for the data I need from CourseList class.

Does anyone have any ideas???

Header File

```
class CourseList 
{
    private:
    struct CourseNode
    {
        int CRN;
        char letterGrade;
        CourseNode *next;
    };
    int length;
    CourseNode *listData;
public:
    CourseList(); 
    CourseList(const CourseList& otherList);
    ~CourseList(); 




};
```

CPP File

```
CourseList::CourseList(const CourseList& otherList)
{
length = otherList.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    CourseNode* temp = new CourseNode;
    temp->CRN = otherList.listData->CRN;
    temp->letterGrade = otherList.listData->letterGrade;
    temp->next = otherList.listData->next;
    listData = temp;
}

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you're trying to do [something like this](http://ideone.com/JcFPfR).

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is broken: it ends up assigning the last element to `listData` instead of the first element.  This means you leak all but the last element of the list.  Also, each time you create a `new CourseNode` you assign its `next` pointer to the exact same thing--for all the copied elements!

Comment: Ignoring that portion for the moment though, I can fix that afterwards.  Any ideas on my original question?

Comment: I don't understand, I'm telling you the specific places where you code is seriously broken, and you want to "ignore" that and focus on...what?

Comment: I thought my issue was with how I was assigning the values and wasn't worrying about the rest, but it appears that my assignments were fine and my error does have to do with updating the pointers.  Someone else tried to help on this, but I've been working with their example for over an hour now and have had absolutely no luck.  Any chance you could offer a little more guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy the value of the `next` member, because that one will point to the original list.

Instead, you'll have to set that in your iteration, i.e. something like this:

```
CourseNode *node = 0;
CourseNode *src = otherList.listData;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    CourseNode *next = new CourseNode();
    if (node)
        node->next = next; // already a previous node; update it
    else
        listData = next; // no previous node; set the very first one

    next->previous = node; // optional in case your list is a double linked list

    // now populate "node" with the original values (i.e. the actual copy operation)
    node->CRN = src->CRN;
    node->letterGrade = src->letterGrade;

    // switch to the next source node
    src = src->next;
}
```

Comment: The population of the original values is the difficulty I am having.  Yeah there is a mistake in how I am moving between nodes, I sort of didn't get to that part yet because of the trouble I was having.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user3889565 I've updated my code snippet with that part. Please try to understand what's going on before simply copying and using it though. :)

Comment: according to this I was correct in using otherList.listData->CRN etc.  Unfortunately still getting the same Access violation error even when I make the adjustments so the nodes update properly.  I'll have to keep tweaking with it I guess.

Comment: The problem is, `otherList.listData` will always point to the very first node in your list only. You'll have to advance that pointer as well (`src` in my example).

Comment: Hmm seems that the problem is my next value is NULL for some reason, I'll have to give that a look in the rest of my code.